# Error while converting an iPhone app into one universal app (iPhone and iPad)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios4

I have an iPhone app which requires to be a universal app. Common between iPhone and iPad.

I tried running the same app on iPad. It shows error in console saying:

> dyld: Symbol not found: _UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey

What should be done? What can be wrong?

Comment: Have you implemented local notification in application?

Comment: What ipad version you are using?

Comment: Ya. But does iPad not support local notification?

Comment: i m testing on iPad simulator 3.2 and iPhone simulator 4.1. what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UILocalNotification is a special feature introduced in version 4.0 and later.If you want to use for Ipad update your version to 4.2 which supports UILocalNotification.For Ipad 3.2 only Push-notification is available.

All the best.

Comment: Additionally, the app shouldn't crash on 3.2 :-) So while updating his iPad will "solve" the issue for him, it won't make the issue go away.

Comment: You are also correct,but you can even check that by the code Dark has suggested and can remove the crash...whether the device has updated ios 4 or not

Answer (score 1):

The symbol in question was added in iOS 4.0 and is not available on iOS 3.2. You should guard against this (use of a symbol that is not available on iOS 3.2) by using the following code:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(multitaskingSupported)]) {
    // Post 4.0, symbol is available.
    // Use UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey
} else {
    // Pre 4.0, symbol is not available.
    // Do not reference the symbol here.
}
```

You will likely stumble upon other symbols that are only available since iOS 4.0, you can use the code in all these places.